# how to run "sudo make" and sudo "make install"

Tags: software-installation, lubuntu, makefile, lm-sensors

I've installed lubuntu yesterday and noticed that the fans aren't working and want to try the solution kevbelisle came up with.

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2002668&s=eb1f4490555e8eda4a27df22fdf9708d&p=12024845#post12024845

So, I have downloaded the makefile and the it87.c files and put them into the desktop, and I dont know how to do the next steps.

Could anyone break down the further steps kevbelisle made?

Thanks.

I removed the .txt in the make file and redo all the steps. Here's what I've got

```
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-43-generic'
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-43-generic/arch/x86/Makefile:98: stack protector enabled but no compiler support
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-43-generic/arch/x86/Makefile:113: CONFIG_X86_X32 enabled but no binutils support
make[1]: gcc: Command not found
  CC [M]  /home/analog/Desktop/New/it87.o
/bin/sh: 1: gcc: not found
make[2]: *** [/home/analog/Desktop/New/it87.o] Error 127
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/analog/Desktop/New] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-43-generic'
make: *** [modules] Error 2
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error messages show missing make gcc etc.
Install the `build-essential` meta-package to get the development tools.

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

Answer (score 5):

The `it87` kernel module is in the `linux-image-extra` package.

```
sudo apt-get install linux-image-extra-$(uname -r)
```

Answer (score -2):

Open a terminal, navigate to the base directory of the thing you want to install, then simply type

```
./configure && make && sudo make install
```

Comment: Hello. The terminal gave me this make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop. I've noticed my makefile is in .txt format. Is it right?

Comment: No, it should be named Makefile with no extension

Comment: Also, this edit may help.

Comment: See the main post, I could not paste the code here.

Comment: I have no clue what you did wrong

Comment: It says gcc not found. Is there anyway I could install it?

Comment: Yes, run: sudo apt-get install gcc

Comment: okay thanks. I think imma create another post cause this one's solved.

Comment: Mark it as correct, then.

Comment: @argarevarg: Why would you run `configure` and `make` with `sudo`?